# Use nc pins of 5 inch HDMI touchscreen

Tags: gpio, touchscreen

I recently bought 5 inch HDMI touchscreen (see link below) .
It Places on top of the RPi gpio and consume a lot of them !!
But unfortunatly 12 pins (like USART and I2C) are nc !! (see link below)

http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD

My question is how can i use those pins? and why they use such a huge connector with many nc pins

And please can you explain specifically what should i do (perhaps with an image). I'm pretty new to this

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the nc pins by connecting the screen to the pi with male to female jumper wires or using something like the Adafruit Pi Cobbler, instead of placing the screen directly on the PI

Answer (score 1):

If your technical skills are good or if your using a Raspberry Pi Zero that came with no pins installed you can use a extra long 2x20-Pin 40P 2.54mm 0.1" Female Header Long Pin 12.2mm connector in place of the install pin header (soldering required).  This will put male pins on one side of the PI board and female pins on the other side.
Keep in mind the pins on the bottom side will be inverted.

Answer (score 1):

A big connector with lots of NC pins is used to provide mechanical stability: this connector is the only thing that holds the RPi and the display together. A smaller connector could easily unplug, and the [rigid HDMI connector](http://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/f/f3/5inch-HDMI-LCD-User-Manual-2.JPG) would then badly damage the HDMI ports on your RPi, the display, or both.

This HDMI connector also makes it impossible to use GPIO splitter directly: you need to keep your RPi at a fixed distance from the touch-screen for this link to fit.

Basically, if you need access to GPIO and a touch-screen, the best solution is to buy a touch-screen which connects to USB. This has the advantage to work with any SBC, not only Raspberry Pi. However, if you want to use the touch-screen you have, you'll have to use a [short HDMI cable](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1scNKKXXXXXbNXXXXq6xXFXXXu/Flat-font-b-HDMI-b-font-Male-to-Male-Converter-Adapter-Short-font-b-Cable-b.jpg) instead of the included connector, and make GPIO connections either using a splitter or jumper cables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a splitter.

Examples:

- https://www.piborg.org/triborg
- https://www.rasppishop.de/Rirack-Piface-Raspberry-Pi
- https://www.pi-shop.ch/pimoroni-black-hat-hack3r-mini-kit

I'll leave it to your imagination on how to use this.